# Regular expression in find command in bash

Tags: regex, shell, find

why 'save$' can not match the file named `save`?

```
root@debian:/home/tiger# ls /home/test
save
root@debian:/home/tiger# find /home/test -regex 'save$'
root@debian:/home/tiger# find /home/test -regex '.*save$'
/home/test/save
```

Comment: This question is about "software tools commonly used by programmers", so I think it should be reopened.

Comment: The question could be reworded like this: Why does `find DIR -regex` treat the regex as if it always had a leading `^` anchor and a trailing `$` anchor?

Answer (score 1):

Because the regex is matched against the full path(i.e. /home/test/save) instead of just on the file name 'save'.

Comment: usually you need the `^` and `$` anchors to match on the whole string, and, as the example by the OP shows, the `$` is allowed. But it's as if there were an implicit `^` too. The question remains: Why?